# Reverse Array with given sentinel value

Tags: c++

FYI: I am new to programming.

I have an `arraysize` of `10` and the sentinel value is `0`.

My original array is `[1 2 3]` ( user input)  but my reverse is `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 1]`.

I need help to make my reverse array `[3 2 1`].

Here is my code:

```
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize/2; i++) 
    {         
     temp = array[arraysize-1-i];
     array[arraysize - i - 1] = array[i];
     array[i] = temp;
    }

    cout << "The reverse array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
     cout << array[i]<< ' ';
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: Then why are you allocating of size `arraysize` when you have only 3 elements (less than `arraysize` length)?

Comment: Yes, that might be the easy solution but we are not supposed to do that way.

Comment: Ahmed, it didn't quite solve the problem. The original array 1 2 3 and the reverse was 3 1 2

Comment: I have tested it and I am geting `[3 2 1]`, you might be doing something wrong. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: can you explain what a sentinel value is supposed to be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to find the **actual length** of the array, before performing the **reverse** operation, and then use that length for all further operations.

Like this:

```
int actualArraySize = 0;

while(actualArraySize < arraysize && array[actualArraySize]!=0)
{
 actualArraySize++;
}

int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < actualArraySize/2; i++)
{
  temp = array[actualArraySize-1-i];
  array[actualArraySize - i - 1] = array[i];
  array[i] = temp;
}

cout << "The reverse array: ";
for (int i = 0; i < actualArraySize; i++)
  cout << array[i]<< ' ';
cout << endl;
```

Note that, `actualArraySize` can be less than or equal to `arraysize`, but, not more than it, because of the condition in `while(actualArraySize < arraysize && array[actualArraySize]!=0)`, which means that stop when either a `0` is found or the size of the array is reached.

Comment: int temp;
      int actualArraySize = 0;
      
  while (actualArraySize < arraysize && array[actualArraySize] != 0){
          actualArraySize ++;
      for (int i = 0; i < actualArraySize/2; i++) 
         {
             
          temp = array[actualArraySize-1-i];
          array[actualArraySize - i - 1] = array[i];
          array[i] = temp;
        }
  } 
       cout << "The reverse array: ";
       for (int i = 0; i < actualArraySize; i++)
          cout << array[i]<< ' ';
       cout << endl;
          
   return 0;

}

Comment: @Siri You have added braces `{}` to `while` in the wrong way. Please see the post, I have edited it to include the braces `{}` for `while`. Note that, if there are no braces `{}` after a control statement, it affects just the one line below it.

Comment: @Siri Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Answer (score 4):

Just use the standard library algorithms

```
auto end = std::find(std::begin(array),std::end(array),0);
std::reverse(std::begin(array),end);
//And if you only want to print the non-zero values:
size_t effectiveArraySize = end - std::begin(array);
```

---

If the fixed size array is not part of your requirement, you should put your user data in a vector that automaticaly grows as large as you need, instead of using an array that might turn out to be too small:

```
std::vector<int> v;
while(true) {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    if (t == 0) {
       break;
    }
    v.push_back(t);       
}
std::reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
```

That way, you don't have any sentinel values in your array / vector to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Using the respective functions from the STL (`std::reverse` and `std::find`) is better, I was just guessing that you are bound to implement this on your own.*

---

*Step one*: Write a proper reverse function. One that takes (a pointer to) the beginning as well as (a pointer to) the end of the range that should be reversed.

*Step two*: Write a function to find (the first position of) your sentinel in an array (given via beginning and end, again)

*Step three*: Connect the two: Reverse from the beginning to the position of your sentinel.

Example without templates:

```
void reverse(int * from, int * to) {
  while ((to - from) > 1) {
    --to;
    int temp = *from;
    *from = *to;
    *to = temp;
    ++from;
  }
}

int const * find(int const * from,
                 int const * const to,
                 int const value) {
  while ((from != to) && (*from != value)) {
    ++from;
  }
  return from;
}

void reverse_until (int * const from,
                                  int * const to,
                                  int const sentinel) {
  int const * const position_sentinel = find(from, to, sentinel);
  reverse(from, from + (position_sentinel - from));
  // return the sentinel position from this function
  // if you want only the reversed part
}
```

Tested with:

```
int main() {
  int test[10];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    test [i] = i + 1;
  }
  reverse_until (test, test + 10, 6);
  copy(test, test + 10, ostream_iterator<int>{cout, " "});
  return 0;
}
```

[(live here)](http://ideone.com/GYa4aT)